# Удалить атрибуты тегов div

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Как реализовать следующее: в переменной какой-то текст, нужно найти там все теги div и удалить у них все атрибуты, кроме class и id, например:

```
<div class="gffh" title="gffhh" id="gfgf"> менялось на <div class="gffh" id="gfgf">
<div name="gghh" title="gffhh" id="gfgf"> менялось на <div id="gfgf">
```

Ну и тому подобное.

Comment: Как сказал один мой коллега: "Каждый раз, когда ты парсишь HTML с помощью регулярок, где-то в мире умирает котёнок. Подумай - стоит ли ?"

Comment: стоит (не люблю котов)

Answer (score 2):

Если не ошибаюсь, скрипт выглядит так и не включает в себя регулярки.

```
var d = document.getElementsByTagName('div'), i = d.length, j;
while(i--){
    j = d[i].attributes.length;
    while(j--){
        if(d[i].attributes[j].name != 'id' && d[i].attributes[j].name != 'class'){
            d[i].removeAttribute(d[i].attributes[j].name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: мне нужно работать с текстом именно, т.е. в переменной код (значение textarea), а в нём уже и проводить изменения, нужны регулярки))))

Comment: создайте динамически ``<div style="display:none">``, присвойте ему innerHTML значение в textarea и работайте с dom'ом. В примере выше будет не ``document.getElementsByTagName``, а ``div.getElementsByTagName``.

Comment: не оч понял, а на примере?

Comment: мне именно через регулярку надо, не буду же весь свой код переписывать, этот вариант не подходит

Answer (score 1):

Регулярные выражения, вообще говоря, не предназначены для парсинга html. Лучше использовать имеющиеся возможности браузера. Например, загрузить данные в невидимый div, и работать далее с DOM'ом...